# How to set the image size in Vis.js network graph

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js, data-visualization, chap-links-library

I am building a network graph using vis.js

The problem is, **how do I make all the images the same size**?
[image: vis.js network graph]
(see live example here --> [comparison of wordpress & drupal](http://www.techwars.io/fight/wordpress/drupal/#more-comparisons))

here's the graph code:

```
    var nodes = [];
    nodes.push({
        id: 7,
        shape: 'image',
        image: '/static/windows8_icons/PNG/Industry/circuit/circuit-26.png',
        label: 'sharepoint',
        widthMin: 20,
        widthMax: 20
    });
    edges.push({
        from: 1,
        to: 7,
        length: 100
    });

    var data = {
        nodes: nodes,
        edges: edges
    };

    var options = {
        smoothCurves: false,
        stabilize: false,
        nodes: {
            shape: 'image',
            radius: 24,
            fontSize: 18,
            widthMin: 20,
            widthMax: 20
        },
        edges: {
            width: 2
        }
    };
    network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

Comment: are your .png files all the same dimensions starting out?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it.. Obviously the files are not the same size to begin with :(

Comment: I have same problem, have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Go for size attribute of node.

Example

```
nodes:{shape:'image',size:20}
```

Reference: http://visjs.org/docs/network/nodes.html

Comment: That sets the size of the node itself, not the image inside the node.

Comment: Since node type is 'image', this will serve the purpose of changing image size.